# Pandas: Dropping Duplicate Values But Keeping How Many Values in Another Column

Tags: python, database, dataframe, counter, series

I have a dataframe of tweets and I have made a user_table accordingly. I want to see which users are most active.

I am already able to drop duplicate values with

```python
from collections import Counter
user_list = user_table['user.id'].tolist()
user_count = Counter(user_list) # get dictionary count
user_table.drop_duplicates(subset='user.id', keep = 'first', inplace = True) # drops duplicate values
```

However I am about to match each id to the appropriate dictionary and assign to list on ordering, turn that into a pandaseries and then assign a column in user_table to that, but I feel like there should be a more streamlined approach

Answer (score 0):

There is a good way to do it using groupby in DataFrame:

```
df_count = user_table.groupby('user.id').count()
df_count['Count'] = df_count.iloc[:,0] # pick a column, any column works
```

Then, merge this back to the table with unique entries:

```
user_table.drop_duplicates(subset='user.id', keep = 'first', inplace = True)
df_merged = pandas.merge(user_table, df_count, on='user.id', how='left')
```

Comment: I want to see the counts appended as column where all values are the same except duplicates are removed and i know how many were removed based on total count that was just appended